# Passing data dynamically to directive's transcluded controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive for a single popup element. Depending on which of many hundreds of elements that are clicked on, I need to pass different data to the popup when it is displayed. Using a service to store/fetch the data seems like a side-band hack. Storing the data in my top-level controller and allowing the popup controller to inherit seems like poor encapsulation. I'd like to have an isolate scope in the directive and have the popup controller inherit from that. This doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts? Is $broadcast my only option?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working with AngularJS 1.x.  I think directive Transclusion is what you are looking for.  Transclusion provides a way to include markup that is bound to the parent controller inside the content area of a directive.

Check out this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/78lM8U9rUk6Zx3Z1RNU4?p=preview) which is taken from the [AngularJS documentation](https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-1-5-multi-slot-transclusion/).

```
 .directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: {
        'title': '?paneTitle',
        'body': 'paneBody',
        'footer': '?paneFooter'
      },
      template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                  '<div class="title" ng-transclude="title">Fallback Title</div>' +
                  '<div **ng-transclude="body"**></div>' +
                  '<div class="footer" **ng-transclude="footer"**>Fallback Footer</div>' +
                '</div>'
    };

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input ng-model="title" aria-label="title"> <br/>
  <textarea ng-model="text" aria-label="text"></textarea> <br/>
  <pane>
    <pane-title><a ng-href="{{link}}">{{title}}</a></pane-title>
    <pane-body><p>{{text}}</p></pane-body>
  </pane>
</div>
```

Pane is the directive.  Note that the content contained in pane-title and pane-body are being compiled against the parent controller, but are displayed in the ng-transclude portions of the directive mark-up.

You should be able to use this to get your custom data into your popup without the need of a service or $broadcast.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass data from attributes into the controller's scope. I'm trying to pass data from the directive function itself to the controller's scope. Can I add objects local to the directive's closure to the transclude list?